# SQL query to pick only the last part of Post_Code column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen a few of these questions asked but haven't spotted one that's helped!! I'm trying to select the second part of postcode only.

For example `Post_Code`:

```
'SF87 5NT'
```

So here I would like my SQL query to only return `'5NT'`

Comment: Please tag only the RDBMS you use. Is the only condition you want to fetch everything after the first space or is your real requirement more complex?

Comment: Postgres quick and dirty: `select split_part('SF87 5NT', ' ' , 2); 5NT`.

Comment: Which db is this? SQL Server or Postgres? The answer will vary based on the dbms

Comment: Its MS SQL server

Comment: Then why tag with postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options:

```
declare @Code varchar(50) = 'SF87 5N6'

select
    stuff(@Code, 1, charindex(' ', @Code) , ''),
    substring(@Code, charindex(' ', @Code) + 1, len(@Code)),
    right(@Code, len(@Code) - charindex(' ', @Code)),
    parsename(replace(@Code, ' ', '.'), 1)
```

I personally like the `stuff` approach best when I need to get everything after a certain point. The `substring` approach is probably about as good (and more flexible if you need to excise a chunk with stuff after it). The last two, I would not probably recommend, since they're kind of like going around your back to get to your elbow, but they do show some additional ways can manipulate the string.